# AngularJS. How can I share a single service between two apps

Tags: angularjs

I have inherited an AngularJS project that uses one app per page. The purpose is to mostly get realtime data binding. Can I create a service that is shared between the apps. The existing code is below.

Currently to get the modalService to work I need to copy a version for each app... in this case the AccountSettings stuff uses modalService2. Otherwise I get an error in the angular.module statement.

Is there a way that modalService can be share by both the PortfolioBuilder stuff and the AccountSettings stuff?

in PortfolioBuilderController.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('portfolioBuilder', ['filters', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller('PortfolioBuilderController', [
        '$window', '$scope', '$log', '$timeout', 'PortfolioBuilder', 'modalService',
        function ($window, $scope, $log, $timeout, PortfolioBuilder, modalService) {
            $scope.portfolioBuilder = PortfolioBuilder;
        ... all the portfolioBuilder controller functions ...
        }]);
})();
```

in AccountSettingsController.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('accountSettings', ['filters', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller('AccountSettingsController', [
        '$window', '$scope', '$log', '$timeout', 'AccountSettings', 'modalService2',
        function ($window, $scope, $log, $timeout, AccountSettings, modalService2) {
            $scope.accountSettings = AccountSettings;
        ... all the accountSettings controller functions ...
        }]);
})();
```

in PortfolioBuilderService.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('portfolioBuilder') || app;
    app.factory('PortfolioBuilder', ['$rootScope', '$window', '$timeout', '$log', '$http', 'modalService',
        function ($rootScope, $window, $timeout, $log, $http, modalService) {
        ... all the portfolioBuilder service functions ...
        }]);
})();
```

in AccountSettingsService.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('accountSettings') || app;
    app.factory('AccountSettings', ['$rootScope', '$window', '$timeout', '$log', '$http', 'modalService2',
        function ($rootScope, $window, $timeout, $log, $http, modalService2) {
        ... all the portfolioBuilder service functions ...
        }]);
})();
```

in modalService.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('portfolioBuilder') || app; 
    app.service('modalService', ['$modal', '$log',
        function ($modal, $log) {
        ... all the modalService functions ...
        }]);
})();
```

in modalService2.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('accountSettings') || app; 
    app.service('modalService2', ['$modal', '$log',
        function ($modal, $log) {
        ... all the modalService functions ...
        }]);
})();
```

Comment: Re-factor the modalService into its own module and declare that as adependency in the two modules that use it.

Comment: As georgeawg said, or ... define a module for reusable/shareable components and inject it where necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new module `modal.mod` as `modal.module.js`:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('modal.mod',[]) ; 
    app.service('modalService', ['$modal', '$log',
        function ($modal, $log) {
        ... all the modalService functions ...
        }]);
})();
```

Inject in module `portfolioBuilder` of `PortfolioBuilderController.js`

```
(function () {
    'use strict'; 
    // injecting "modal.mod" in the "portfolioBuilder"
    var app = angular.module('portfolioBuilder', ['modal.mod','filters', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller('PortfolioBuilderController', [
        '$window', '$scope', '$log', '$timeout', 'PortfolioBuilder', 'modalService',
        function ($window, $scope, $log, $timeout, PortfolioBuilder, modalService) {
            $scope.portfolioBuilder = PortfolioBuilder;
        ... all the portfolioBuilder controller functions ...
        }]);
})();
```

Similarly in `AccountSettingsController.js`:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    // injecting "modal.mod" in the "accountSettings"
    var app = angular.module('accountSettings', ['modal.mod','filters', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller('AccountSettingsController', [
        '$window', '$scope', '$log', '$timeout', 'AccountSettings', 'modalService',
        function ($window, $scope, $log, $timeout, AccountSettings, modalService) {
            $scope.accountSettings = AccountSettings;
        ... all the accountSettings controller functions ...
        }]);
})();
```

Similarly, inject `modal.mod` in any module that requires `modalService`.

Comment: minor edit... in modalService.js I was missing a ( at the very beginning of modalService.js... I updated my question... if you could update the answer too... thanks!

Comment: @BrianRice : Thanks and Done ! :)